# What is the syntax for a function-pointer typedef?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, typedef

I am working on a thread pool and to avoid long qualifier names I would like to use `typedef` declaration.

But it is not as easy as it seems to be:

```
typedef unsigned ( __stdcall *start_address )( void * ) task;
```

When I tried it that way I got:

```
error C3646: 'task' : unknown override specifier
```

error, after playing for a little while with this declaration I'm stuck and can't find any reasonable solution to use to declare such type of `typedef`.

Comment: what should "task" mean? is it some special keyword?

Comment: Task is a word which I want to use instead of this long declaration. But nevermind, the solution is found. Thanks to all, specially pb2q :)

Comment: Be warned: Implementig a reasonably good thread pool is far from trivial. Did you consider to use an existing implementation?

Comment: Well it is in educational purposes, so I think I will take a risk :)

Comment: @unresolved_external: and you didn't wonder what `start_address`  was for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When creating a `typedef` alias for a function pointer, the alias is in the function *name* position, so use:

```
typedef unsigned (__stdcall *task )(void *);
```

`task` is now a type alias for: *pointer to a function taking a `void` pointer and returning `unsigned`*.

Comment: @unresolved_external Don't forget to accept this answer if is the best solution to your problem (which from your comment it seems it is).

Comment: @unresolved_external: Forgetting function pointer syntax in C is nothing to be ashamed of :D

Comment: that sucks ... i like C++, but the syntax is really retarded, when it comes to pointers and constants

Answer (score 7):

Since hmjd's answer has been deleted...

In C++11 a whole newsome *alias* syntax has been developed, to make such things much easier:

```
using task = unsigned (__stdcall*)(void*);
```

is equivalent the to `typedef unsigned (__stdcall* task)(void*);` (note the position of the alias in the middle of the function signature...).

It can also be used for templates:

```
template <typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;

int main() {
    Vec<int> x;
}
```

This syntax is quite nicer than the old one (and for templates, actually makes template aliasing possible) but does require a quite newish compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: The `__stdcall` part might break your code under different compilers / compiler settings (unless the function is explicitly declared as `__stdcall`, too). I'd stick to the default calling convention only using proprietary compiler extensions having good reaons.

Comment: Or use a macro that is `#define`'d to either `__stdcall` or something else depending on the compiler.  Although typically you only explicitly declare the calling convention when interacting with a (usually platform-specific) library that has a defined calling convention.